# info in array comes out blank

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I seem to be having a problem and im a little lost on how I can proceed to fix it. Im trying to echo out some data from an array into another array, but the problem is without me using print_r or echo the info comes back blank, I dont know why it keeps doing that. This is what I have and I know it should work but it just isnt.

```
<?php   

$number = 0;
foreach($picture_info as $path => $picture_location){ ?>

<?php $mymap = new Mappress_Map(array("width" => 490, "height" => 290));

$mypoi_1 = new Mappress_Poi(array("title" => "$picture_location->name", "body" => "$picture_location->city, $picture_location->state" ,"point" => array("lat" => "$picture_location->latitude", "lng" => "$picture_location->longitude")));
```

The problem is here where it says $picture_location->latitude and longitude as you can see this is a array and the infomation is in the array but the result comes out blank however if i use echo $picture_location->latitude or print_r it will shows the results however i cant do that inside of a array because its invalid coding

```
$mymap->pois = array($mypoi_1);

echo $mymap->display(array("directions"=>"none")); ?>

<?php echo "<div class='search'>reviews for &nbsp;<strong>".urldecode($loc)."</strong> area</div>"; ?>

<?php $number++; if($number == 1) break; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope I am being descriptive about this and any help on what I can do is appreciated

Comment: Can you post an example of `$picture_info`?

Comment: its pretty long so I posted it in pastebin http://pastebin.com/2W1RWyMe

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in all that code do you actually assign anything to `$loc`, so you're ouputting an empty var.

Major syntax problems with your code:

1 - You're jumping in and out of "php mode" frequently, for no good reason. There's no point in doing a `?>` if you're just going to have a `<?php` on the next line.

2 - You're uselessly using `" "` quoted strings, just to pass in a variable. e.g.

```
array("title" => "$picture_location->name"
```

should just be:

```
array("title" => $picture_location->name
```

in other words:

```
$x = "Hello"
$y = "$x";  // useless use of double-quotes
$y = $x; // proper usage
```

Comment: I tried your way before I posted here and its not the problem for why not shows unless I echo it out. please check the pastebin file posted above

Comment: What exactly is not showing? the `echo $mymap->display(array("directions"=>"none"));`? You'd probably want to do `$loc = $mymap->display(array("directions"=>"none"));`, as I said above: $loc isn't defined anywhere in your code EXCEPT where you try to output it.

Comment: this is the problem I am having not anywhere else - point" => array("lat" => $picture_location->latitude, "lng" => $picture_location->longitude)));